# How to get the table name from model class name in TYPO3 extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

What is the best way to get the table name from a specific object?
Is there something like:

```
$tableName = Utility::doSomeMagic($object);
```

So that you get tx_extkey_domain_model_myobject from Vendor\Extkey\Domain\Model\MyObject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the DataMapper to get the table name of a model. It is used internally by the Repositories(indirectly at least) to tell what they are dealing with. You can get yourself an instance of the DataMapper and use it like so:

```
$className = \MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\SomeModel::class;
$dataMapper = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::class);
$tableName = $dataMapper->getDataMap($className)->getTableName();
```

Take a look at the `SqlDebuggerUtility` from [this github repository](https://github.com/the-coding-owl/sql_debug/blob/master/Classes/Utilities/SqlDebuggerUtility.php), which is using the DataMapper to get the tablename of a QueryResult object to debug the SQL statements.

Answer (score 4):

on TYPO3 9.x

you need

```
$className = get_class($this);
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$dataMapper = $objectManager->get(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::class
);
$tableName = $dataMapper->getDataMap($className)->getTableName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the Update!